# How to setting up environment for tensor flow developement

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I cloned tensorflow repository to my pc. How should I setting up my environment for development?I have no I idea about avaialable files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start simple(not build tensorflow from source by yourslef), you can follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/) link to install it.

Then you can go through [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/) to get familiar with how tensorflow works.

I believe the best documents for tensorflow are all on its official site(As you can see, the two links above are all from the official site of tensorflow).